# Login system with password_verify()

Tags: php, session, password-hash

I'm trying to make a login system with hashed passwords. 
What is supposed to happen is after I click on the submit button a session should be created and I should be redirected to home.php. If input data doesn't match the data inside the database I should get "Error 1" or "Error 2" alerts.


My problem is that when I click on a submit button all that happens is that I get redirected to login.php. I get no errors and no alerts, only blank screen with login.php URL.

I'm trying to figure how to make the password_verify() part work.  Any kind of help is appreciated.

Picture of database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyBTK.jpg

Picture of what happens after a login attempt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Myk.jpg

Form code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title> Login now! </title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<header>

  <div class="alignRight">
    <a href="registration.html"> Register </a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
  </div>

  <div class="alignLeft">
    <a href="contact.html"> Contact us </a> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a href="aboutus.html"> About us </a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <a href="news.html"> News </a>
  </div>

</header>

<h1> Welcome back! </h1>

<h2> Log in to continue with your work. </h2> 

<form name="login-form" id="login-form" action="login.php" method="post">

    <input class="_40" type="text" name="username"  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}" 
placeholder="Username"  required /> 

    <br />

    <input class="_40" type="password" name="pwd"  placeholder="Password"  required />

    <br />

    <input id="loginSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit"  /> 

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php


session_start();

$servername ="localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

mysqli_select_db($link, "users");


$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["username"]);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["pwd"]); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if(($result->num_rows > 0))
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if(password_verify($pwd, $row["Hash"]))
        {
            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
            header("location:home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("Error 1")</script>';
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<script>alert("Error2")</script>';
}


?>
```

Comment: You should use a prepared statement rather than escaping the strings. And you definitely should not escape the password. You aren't using it in the query and the escaping could easily interfere with the hash comparison.

Comment: how is your db name? db name and table name = users??

Comment: The blank screen means most likely one of two things. One is a fatal error without error reporting enabled, and the other is that $result->num_rows is not greater than zero, meaning there would be no output or redirection.

Comment: what is your error reporting set to, can you maybe add `error_reporting(-1);` at the start of your script and post the output?

Comment: I added
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
Still no errors after submission. And in case  that $result ->num_rows isn't greater than zero, echo '<script>alert("Error2")</script>'; should happen.

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating passwords in any way. Now, what is the value of `$row["Hash"]` and the password column's length?

Comment: Ah yeah, I misread that initially. The indentation edit helped :-)

Comment: The value of $row["Hash"] should be the value of column "Hash" of the database. (Something like $2y$10$oNiLQYzDNIJgfDbuUK8F9eW5emgawmCufs0hDyIc7Ke) I do not have the password column, only Hash. It's length is 255.

Comment: Yeah I'm kinda new in here. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see the problem.

It looks like you're probably fetching the only row from the results before the if

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then when you fetch again here, there's nothing left to fetch.

```
if(($result->num_rows > 0))
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

(I'm assuming the query will only return one row since username is unique.)

Comment: Yep! I removed $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); and the code works properly. Thank you so much for your assistance, much appreciated!

Comment: @Don'tPanic Heh. For some reason, that made me raise a brow and I couldn't put my finger on it, but you did. Way to go!

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner. I was actually still looking for a parse error when I noticed that bit :-D

Comment: Welcome @Don'tPanic Sometimes it's because of the way the hash was stored but it wasn't that this time. I gave the OP [a slight nudge up there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60289767/login-system-with-password-verify/60290079?noredirect=1#comment106646753_60289767) to see if they will catch the wave ;-) Cheers